# Find $n(B\setminus A).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the sets $A$ and $B$ be subset of the universal set $U$ with $n(A\setminus B)=3, n(A')=8$ and $n(B')=7.$ Find $n(B\setminus A).$
Help me please. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As you have probably found by now, it is expected that you will provide enough context for a Question that Readers can discern where your difficulty lies.  Are you troubled by the notation?  By the principle of inclusion/exclusion?  Without more details, "Help me please" is asking Readers to take a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that 
$$B'\cup (B\setminus A)=B'\cup A'=(A\setminus B)\cup A'.$$
Moerover $B'$ and $(B\setminus A)$ are disjoint. The same for $(A\setminus B)$ and $A'$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$n(A\setminus B)=x=3$$
$$n(A')=y+z=8$$
$$n(B')=x+y=7$$
$$n(B\setminus A)=z=?$$

Now we have:
$x=3$

$x+y=7\Rightarrow y=4$

$y+z=8\Rightarrow z=4$

Finally
$$n(B\setminus A)=z=4$$

I hope help you.

Comment: Why $n(A') =y+z$? What about elements in $U\setminus (A\cup B) $? If you take those into account, the correct answer is $4$ and not $3$.

Comment: I corrected, by solve equations, speeding i made 'mistake'

Comment: Your method is still wrong. $n(A') $ is not $y+z $ it is $z+u$ where $u=n((A \cup B)') $